# Как лучше провести операцию с объектом pandas.core.series.Series в Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.5

Объект класса `Standard_deviation` подаёт сигналы для тестирования торговой системы. Логика следующая: есть канал скользящая средняя +- стандартное отклонение, как только цена актива превышает верхнюю границу этого канала считаем тренд восходящим до тех пор, пока цена не опуститься за нижнюю границу - тогда тренд считается нисходящим до тех пор пока она опять не поднимется до верней границы. Для интеграции с другими классами нужен датасет содержащий столбец "signal" с двумя значениями 1 и -1 отображающими соответственно восходящий и нисходящий тренды.

В дальнейшем этот индикатор в системе с другими будет использоваться для сравнения результатов торговых стратегий на большом количестве активов и с изменением параметров (к примеру, надо проверить насколько хорошо каждое значение скользящего среднего из диапазона [10:30] показывает себя на каждом активе из 40, да ещё и в системе с другими индикаторами) поэтому важно найти способ подачи сигнала, оптимальный с точки зрения длительности исполнения и занимаемой памяти. Как лучше реализовать метод "trend" в данном классе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Standard_deviation:
    def __init__(self, ticker, SMA, start, end):
        self.SMA = SMA
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.seq = web.DataReader(ticker, start=start, end=end, data_source='yahoo')
    def advise(self, regime):
        self.seq['SD'] = round(self.seq['Close'].rolling(window=self.SMA).std(), 2)
        self.seq['SMA'] = round(self.seq['Close'].rolling(window=self.SMA).mean(), 2)
        self.seq = self.seq.dropna()
        self.seq['signal'] = 0
        if regime == "oscillation":
            self.seq['signal'] = np.where(self.seq['Close'] > self.seq['SMA'] + self.seq['SD'], -1, self.seq['signal'])
            self.seq['signal'] = np.where(self.seq['Close'] < self.seq['SMA'] - self.seq['SD'], 1, self.seq['signal'])
        if regime == "trend":
            self.seq['signal'] = np.where(self.seq['Close'] > self.seq['SMA'] + self.seq['SD'], 1, self.seq['signal'])
            self.seq['signal'] = np.where(self.seq['Close'] < self.seq['SMA'] - self.seq['SD'], -1, self.seq['signal'])  
        return self.seq[['signal', 'SMA', 'SD', 'Close']]
    def plot(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 12))
        ax.plot(self.seq.index, self.seq['Close'])
        ax.plot(self.seq.index, self.seq['SMA'] + self.seq['SD'])
        ax.plot(self.seq.index, self.seq['SMA'] - self.seq['SD'])

example = Standard_deviation('GAZP.ME', 20, '1/1/2019', '07/04/2019')
example.advise('trend')
```

На выходе получается следующий датасет, где тренд отмечен только для значений вне границ канала

```
Date        signal  SMA SD    Close
2019-01-31  1   159.96  2.31    162.820007
2019-02-01  1   160.31  2.25    163.330002
2019-02-04  1   160.51  2.32    163.199997
2019-02-05  1   160.81  2.40    164.250000
2019-02-06  0   160.96  2.46    163.210007
2019-02-07  0   160.97  2.45    160.389999
2019-02-08  0   160.91  2.47    159.800003
2019-02-11  0   160.95  2.47    161.289993
2019-02-12  1   161.22  2.45    163.679993
2019-02-13  0   161.34  2.28    159.270004
2019-02-14  -1  161.25  2.50    155.149994
2019-02-15  0   161.24  2.51    159.039993
2019-02-18  -1  161.14  2.65    156.429993
2019-02-19  -1  160.92  3.05    154.029999
2019-02-20  -1  160.65  3.37    154.429993
2019-02-21  -1  160.28  3.73    153.500000
2019-02-22  -1  159.87  3.88    154.639999
2019-02-25  -1  159.57  4.05    154.600006
```

А необходимо уловить его и между этими случаями, то есть после 1 должны идти 1 до первой -1 и наоборот

```
Date        signal  SMA SD    Close
2019-01-31  1   159.96  2.31    162.820007
2019-02-01  1   160.31  2.25    163.330002
2019-02-04  1   160.51  2.32    163.199997
2019-02-05  1   160.81  2.40    164.250000
2019-02-06  1   160.96  2.46    163.210007
2019-02-07  1   160.97  2.45    160.389999
2019-02-08  1   160.91  2.47    159.800003
2019-02-11  1   160.95  2.47    161.289993
2019-02-12  1   161.22  2.45    163.679993
2019-02-13  1   161.34  2.28    159.270004
2019-02-14  -1  161.25  2.50    155.149994
2019-02-15  -1  161.24  2.51    159.039993
2019-02-18  -1  161.14  2.65    156.429993
2019-02-19  -1  160.92  3.05    154.029999
2019-02-20  -1  160.65  3.37    154.429993
2019-02-21  -1  160.28  3.73    153.500000
2019-02-22  -1  159.87  3.88    154.639999
2019-02-25  -1  159.57  4.05    154.600006
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете привести в вопросе выходной датасет - то, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вам подойдет такое решение:

```
df.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)
df['signal'] = df['signal'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

То есть, сначала меняем нули на `NaN`, а затем пользуемся методом `fillna`. При этом на выходе в колонке `signal` у вас будут `float`, но это легко можно будет исправить с помощью метода `.astype()`:

```
          Date  signal     SMA    SD       Close
0   2019-01-31     1.0  159.96  2.31  162.820007
1   2019-02-01     1.0  160.31  2.25  163.330002
2   2019-02-04     1.0  160.51  2.32  163.199997
3   2019-02-05     1.0  160.81  2.40  164.250000
4   2019-02-06     1.0  160.96  2.46  163.210007
5   2019-02-07     1.0  160.97  2.45  160.389999
6   2019-02-08     1.0  160.91  2.47  159.800003
7   2019-02-11     1.0  160.95  2.47  161.289993
8   2019-02-12     1.0  161.22  2.45  163.679993
9   2019-02-13     1.0  161.34  2.28  159.270004
10  2019-02-14    -1.0  161.25  2.50  155.149994
11  2019-02-15    -1.0  161.24  2.51  159.039993
12  2019-02-18    -1.0  161.14  2.65  156.429993
13  2019-02-19    -1.0  160.92  3.05  154.029999
14  2019-02-20    -1.0  160.65  3.37  154.429993
15  2019-02-21    -1.0  160.28  3.73  153.500000
16  2019-02-22    -1.0  159.87  3.88  154.639999
17  2019-02-25    -1.0  159.57  4.05  154.600006
```

Минус подобного метода в том, что, несмотря не эффективность, `replace` поменяет `0` на `NaN` во всем df.

**UPDATE**

Как верно заметил MaxU, вы можете сразу присвоить `NaN` вместо `0` в столбце 'signal' в методе `advise` вашего класса `Standard_deviation`:

```
...
    self.seq = self.seq.dropna()
    self.seq['signal'] = 0 #<-- заменить на np.nan
    if regime == "oscillation":
...
```

В этом случае задача становится еще более тривиальной и вы избежите ненужных замен по всему датафрейму.

Comment: проще и правильнее будет заменить в методе `advise()`: `self.seq['signal'] = 0` --> `self.seq['signal'] = np.nan`